# Android Open CV make: *** Android NDK: Aborting

Tags: android-ndk

![I got this error when i try to run sample projects of opencv][1]

![1]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zoTZ.png)

Comment: hi... you might want to give more details in the question... like what sample were you trying to run and whether other NDK projects have worked successfully before...

Comment: @user1055604 no sample project run. I  add ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd in environmental variable.. but still it isn't working.. please tell me whether NDK is necessary for OPENCV projects or not??